# Import a iPython Custom Widget Function (File Structure?)

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, ipython, jupyter

I am trying to follow [this](https://github.com/jdfreder/ipython-d3networkx/blob/master/examples/demo%20simple.ipynb) example and [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/quantopian/ipython/blob/master/examples/Interactive%20Widgets/Custom%20Widget%20-%20Hello%20World.ipynb) tutorial to make a D3 widget which displays D3 HTML code to a widget when a function is called. I was able to make it function [within the notebook cells itself using %%javascript](http://puu.sh/mgC5Z/288755ed63.png), but this would be messy for an end user to use.

How can I move the Python D3Widget class definition and Javascript D3View render code to external files so that the user can simply import the file and call the function?

I want the end result to look like [this](https://github.com/jdfreder/ipython-d3plot), where the user can simply import a function and call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Organize your code**

In your notebook root folder create a package for your new widget. For example you can use the following directory structure:

```
helloworld/

    __init__.py
    helloworld_widget.py

    helloworldjs/
        helloworld.view.js

        css/
            helloworld.css
```

**Program the server side**

Inside helloworld/helloworld_widget.py, put your Python class:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from traitlets import Unicode

class HelloWorldWidget(widgets.DOMWidget):
    _view_module = Unicode("nbextensions/helloworld/helloworld_view", sync=True)
    _view_name = Unicode('HelloWorldView', sync=True)
```

That's it with your python code.

**Create the Javascript view**

In helloworld/helloworldjs/helloworld.view.js program your client side:

```
define(["nbextensions/widgets/widgets/js/widget"], function(widget) {

    var HelloWorldView = widget.DOMWidgetView.extend({

        render: function(){
            this.$el.text("Hello world");
        },
    });

    return {HelloWorldView: HelloWorldView}
});
```

Simple, isn't it? Last but not least...

**Deploy the client side to the notebook's extensions folder**

To do that you can program a function in your **init**.py and execute it inside your notebook every time your modify something in your Javascript view.

I use this one very similar to the following:

```
def notebook_install(overwrite=True, user=True):
    import os
    from notebook import install_nbextension
    from notebook.services.config import ConfigManager
    from IPython.display import display, Javascript

    js_path = os.path.join( os.path.dirname(__file__), 'helloworldjs')
    install_nbextension(js_path, overwrite=overwrite,
                        symlink=False, verbose=0, user=user)
```

Now you should be able to execute the following in your notebook:

```
from helloworld.helloworld_widget import HelloWorldWidget
hello = HellowWorldWidget()
hello
```

Enjoy!

Reading carefully this article should also help: https://carreau.gitbooks.io/jupyter-book/content/notebook-extensions.html